# Flutter Dart convert nullable int? to nullable String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I must pass `int?` parameter to method where I can use only `String?` parameter. How to do it shorter?

```dart
void mymethod(String? s)
{
   print(s ?? "Empty");
}
int? a = null;
mymethod(a == null ? null : a.toString()); // how do this line easier?
```

Edit: I can't change parameter `mymethod(String? s)` to `mymethod(int? s)` - it still must be `String?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but you want this ?

```
void mymethod(String? s)
{
   print(s ?? "Empty");
}
int? a; // this could be null already
mymethod(a?.toString()); // "a" could be null, so if it is null it will be set, otherwise it will be set to String
```

[image]

Comment: When `a ? a = null;`, `.toString()` return `"null"`, but I search for similar way, but with return `null` instead of `"null"` when `a ? a = null;`

Comment: That is obvious, but I forgot about it, Yes, `mymethod(a?.toString()); ` is simplest way!
When we use `?.toString()` instead of `.toString()` we receive `null` instead of `"null"`

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
mymethod(a?.toString());
```

But if you want to make the check, my suggestion is to make the function do it.

```
int? a;
mymethod(a);

void mymethod(int? s) {
   String text = "Empty";
   if (s != null) text = s.toString();
   print(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

literally shorter, `""` with `$`can help, with more complex you need use `${}` instead of `$`.

**Example**: `mymethod(a == null ? null : "$a");`

Or you can create an extensiton on `Int?` and just call extension function to transform to `String?`, short, easy and reuseable. you can write the extension code elsewhere and import it where you need it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
void mymethod(int? s) {
    return s?.toString;
}
int? a = null;
mymethod(a);
```